# Use laptop as an access point?

Tags: windows-xp, home-networking, wireless-access-point, connection-sharing

My router is in one room while my laptop has wireless connection with it in another room. In the same room I have a ***PC which doesn't have wireless*** and only option I can connect it to this router is by cable. Is it possible to use my laptop as access point for PC (for example to connect PC and laptop with LAN cable)?

Comment: what operating systems?  this will enable us to give you more OS-specified information....

Comment: Win XP on both computers - one has wireless, one doesn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internet Connection Sharing (in Windows) is your answer...

> Setting Up Internet Connection Sharing
>
> Windows XP: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306126
>
> Windows Vista/7: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Using-ICS-Internet-Connection-Sharing

Basically, your laptop with wireless internet will share that connection with your desktop PC through an Ethernet cable running between the two computers...You will need to go into the properties of your wireless internet on your laptop and check `Allow other network users to connect through this computer's Internet connection`.  The second check box is optional, but I would check it anyway...

[image]

Comment: You mean to connect pc and laptop with cable and laptop and router with cable too?

Comment: thing is that my PC doesnt have antenna so it can't go wireless...

Comment: @ile: my mistake completely. I misread it, and thought your desktop PC did have wireless capabilities.  You would need to use internet connection sharing, by running a cable between the wireless laptop and the desktop PC...see updated answer in a minute...

Comment: In Network Connections I have Local Area Connection and Wireless Connection. I tried this change on first and then on second connection (not possible on both), but I get only "Limited Connectivity" on Local Area Connection

Comment: i also noticed when I allow sharing on Local Area Connection on laptop even without pluging the cable my internet connection on laptop is broken

Comment: Solved - my Local Area Connection wasn't set properly. I used wizard for creating LAN and then it worked with these instructions. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You basically want to use your laptop as a wireless adapter for your PC.  The easiest way to accomplish this is to bridge the network connections of your laptop.  **This will require your laptop to have two network connections (one wired and one wireless) and your PC to have one wired connection.**  Bridging is easy, simply highlight your LAN connection (wired) and wireless connection in the Network Connections menu of your laptop, right click one of them and select Bridge Connections.  It will take a minute or two to create the bridge, but once it is done all you need to do is connect the LAN port (the port that accepts an Ethernet cable) of your laptop to the LAN port of your PC via an Ethernet cable.  You should now have network access on both computers.

Comment: @studiohack I realize this.  Only one machine (the laptop) will need wireless access for this to work.  As long as he can connect to his wireless network with the laptop and can also connect the laptop to the desktop via a wired (Ethernet cable) connection then bridging the connections on his laptop should work for him.